# Get the key value for a given attribute in MSBuild using XmlRead

Tags: msbuild

I have a file containing (among other stuff) an xml structure like this:

```
<exchanges>
    <name deliverycode="11">BIT</name>
    <name deliverycode="92">BOTC</name>
    <name deliverycode="24">BTEC</name>
    <name deliverycode="24">BTEX</name>
    <name deliverycode="60">NPCH</name>
    <name deliverycode="00">TSE</name>
    <name deliverycode="00">TSP</name>
    <name deliverycode="91">UCA</name>
</exchanges>
```

For a given acronym I want the deliverycode number, e.g. "BIT" should return "11", "BOTC" -> "92" etc. I use MSBuild v4.0 and have without success tried the XmlRead task to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [online XPath generators](https://www.google.de/search?q=online%20xpath%20generator&aq=f&oq=online%20xpath%20generator&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62j61.1054&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and XPath evaluators to quickly get the right XPath.

I used [this one](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) to test the following XPath:

```
string(/exchanges//name[text()="BOTC"]/@deliverycode)
```

it produces correct output of `92`

Than you can use **XMLRead** tasks from [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) project to retrieve the value (it looks like you refer to it in your post, so I mention it for the sake of ensuring we are on the same page here).

Note: I don't have a set-up to test the XPath in msbuild environment right now (I tested only with web evaluator I referred to), so minor tweaks may be needed to get it producing the value in msbuild env.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify: I must have this working within an MSBuild script so don't think an online tool is appropriate here.
I use MSBuild only and what I am looking for is something like the reverse of the following:
    <XmlRead Namespace="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd" Prefix="n"       
        XPath="/root/exchanges/name[@deliverycode='92']" XmlFileName="@(CustNumFile)">       
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="name" />    
    </XmlRead>
This one gives me 'BOTC' but I would like to use the XmlRead task in MSBuild (or something else in MSBuild) to pass BOTC to get 92.